# SQL Query With Between ,AND & OR in Where Clauses Not Given Correct Answers

Tags: mysql, vtiger

```
SELECT * 
FROM vtiger_crmentity 
where createdtime BETWEEN '2019-06-11 14:07:47' AND '2019-06-11 14:08:47' 
   OR modifiedtime BETWEEN '2019-06-11 14:07:47' AND '2019-06-11 14:08:47' 
  AND smownerid = '1' 
  AND setype = 'Potentials' 
  AND deleted = '0'`
```

But Not Give Me a Correct answer as i want,
Suggest to Improve.
response from Database with Query.
https://prnt.sc/o0hhq9

Comment: Check precedence od operators https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses for the `OR` condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM vtiger_crmentity 
where (createdtime BETWEEN '2019-06-11 14:07:47' AND '2019-06-11 14:08:47' 
   OR modifiedtime BETWEEN '2019-06-11 14:07:47' AND '2019-06-11 14:08:47')
  AND smownerid = '1' 
  AND setype = 'Potentials' 
  AND deleted = '0'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using parenthesis `()` to segregate OR logic; the updated code can look like

```sql
SELECT *
FROM vtiger_crmentity
WHERE 
    (
        createdtime BETWEEN '2019-06-11 14:07:47' AND '2019-06-11 14:08:47'
        OR
        modifiedtime BETWEEN '2019-06-11 14:07:47' AND '2019-06-11 14:08:47'
    ) 
    AND smownerid = '1' 
    AND setype = 'Potentials' 
    AND deleted = '0'
;
```

Comment: `()` parenthesis.  `[]` brackets

Comment: Update your answer with correct details. replace the bracket as parenthesis. @Dhanushkasasanka

Comment: Thank You .After Read One  articles on w3resource.com . I solved this problems.